# How to sign on existed pdf using podofo?

Tags: podofo

I have a project which uses PoDoFo for digitally signing on pdf. i have done successfully digital signature on new pdf file and how to do on existed pdf file?

Here is my code :

```
    PoDoFo::PdfPage*            pPage;
const char *path1=[path UTF8String];
PoDoFo::PdfSignOutputDevice signer(path1);
// Reserve space for signature
 signer.SetSignatureSize(2048);

PoDoFo::PdfStreamedDocument writer( &signer, PoDoFo::ePdfVersion_1_5 );
 // Disable default appearance
 writer.GetAcroForm(PoDoFo::ePdfCreateObject, PoDoFo::PdfAcroForm::ePdfAcroFormDefaultAppearance_None);

    pPage = writer.CreatePage(PoDoFo::PdfPage::CreateStandardPageSize(PoDoFo::ePdfPageSize_A4 ) );

    TEST_SAFE_OP( CreateSimpleForm( pPage, &writer, *signer.GetSignatureBeacon() ) );

    TEST_SAFE_OP( writer.Close() );
```

Comment: Do you find a solution to sign with Podofo? Could you share your results. Thanks